# Dynamic web application based on MS Access

Tags: web-apps, sql-server, microsoft-access

I am given MS Access file, based on which I need to create a web application with some statistics. The end user is downloading this MS Access file from some third party application, say once a week. So, my application should be able to update statistics whenever user requires it.

I just had an idea to have a page with default statistics and a possibility to upload a newer Access file on the website, which will refresh the statistics accordingly. Do you think this is possible? or maybe you have some better suggestions. I am very confused as I have only recently first heard about MS Access at all, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible. MS Access is a standalone file (.mdb or .accdb), and like a spreadsheet or document file, it can be uploaded, moved, copied, deleted etc.

You probably know that Access is compatible with SQL.

I know your idea will work, because I did that exact thing several years ago.  Except the downloading of the new Access file was automated also, so the whole thing ran by itself.